# character comparison using switch

Tags: c, switch-statement

I'm comparing strings character by character.

Here's a part of my code that's causing problems:

```
switch(line[1]) {
case 'u':
    switch(line[2]) {
    case 't':
        switch(line[3]) {
        case 't':
            switch(line[4]) {
            case 'o':
                switch(line[5]) {
                case 'n':
                    switch(line[6]) {
                    case 's':
                        printf("buttons\n");
                    case ' ':
                        printf("not buttons\n");
                    break;
                    }
                break;
                } 
            break;
            }
        break;
        }
    break;
    }
}
```

For `line[6]`, if an `s` character exists it should print out "buttons", if there's a space, it should print out "not buttons"

If I have a config file that contains:

```
buttons 13
button  3
buttons 3
```

I get:

```
buttons
not buttons
buttons
not buttons
```

If I have:

```
buttons 3
```

I get:

```
buttons
not buttons
```

I get a "buttons" and "not buttons" for every buttons entry and get nothing for the "button 3" entry

thanks

Comment: Please oh please format your code! Don't write everything on a single line, it makes it impossible to read.

Comment: my apologies, I just copied and pasted and did not consider that point :(

Comment: This is the worse pattern I have ever seen, Why on earth would you want such bad looking, unreadable and very badly performing code?

Comment: @AdelAhmed That's is worse, it means that you work with such an unreadable code.

Comment: What made you fall in love with the `switch` statement? Please use the `&&` operator.

Comment: @knm241 Or, in this case, just a simple `strcmp` call.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg yes. Can you believe that code is so hard to read I didn't recognize he was checking the string for "button" vs "buttons"? Specially the one line version missing the b character check.

Comment: Yo dawg, I heard you like `switch`...

Comment: @knm241 I didn't recognize it either at first, because of the obfuscation, but what the OP is doing is just comparing strings in a very weird and obfuscated way.

Comment: @iharob, you are correct, I should work on properly formatting my code, and in general making things simpler
knm, Joachim I think strcmp will definitely be better in this case
I'm working on rewriting this bit
how in the following config:
buttons 3
how can I compare 'buttons' to a string?

Comment: And you could use a `for` loop instead of the `switch` if you didn't know `strcmp()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will always get `not buttons` when there is `buttons` because you are not breaking after `case 's'`.Therefore it won't stop when an `line[6]` is `s`.
And you used all these nested switches just to compare a string.Better use `strcmp` to check if its `buttons` or `button`.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of complicating nested switch, use this

```
FILE * fi;    // input file handle
char line[9], c;

while (feof(fi) == 0) {
    // Read only required chars
    fgets(line, 8, fi);
    line[8] = '\0';
    while ((c = getc(fi)) != '\n' && c != EOF);

    // Simplified comparison
    if (strncmp(line, "button", 6) == 0) {
        if (line[6] == 's') printf("buttons\n");
        else if (line[6] == ' ') printf("not buttons\n");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simpler, cleaner version of the code:

```
if (strncmp(line, "button", 6)==0)
{
  if (line[6]=='s')
  printf("buttons");
  else printf("button");
}
```